# Como encontrar o número mais aproximado com JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um `input` que recebe um valor digitado pelo usuário e um array com 12 valores.. estou percorrendo o array com um ForEach.. pois preciso encontrar o valor mais aproximado do do valor digitado no `input`.. tenho o seguinte código:

```
        $('#possoPagar').keyup(function (e) {
            let valor = $('#possoPagar').val();
            let valorIdeal = 0;

            $.each(parcelas, function (index, item) {
                if (item.valor <= valor && item.valor >= valorIdeal) {
                    valorIdeal = item.valor;

                    $("#vParcela").html(parseFloat(item.valor).toFixed(2).replace('.', ','));
                    nParcelas.val(item.qtdParcelas);
                }
            });
        });
```

O problema é que enquanto ele é menor que o valor da parcela ele não reconhece aquela parcela e as vezes ele acaba trazendo um valor que na verdade não é o mais aproximado, Obrigado!

Comment: É o mais próxima pra cima e pra baixo ou só pra baixo?

Comment: Posta o código de maneira que possamos executar e entender o que você já fez. Cria um exemplo do problema no jsfiddle ou stacksnippet.

Answer (score 2):

[**fonte - brother**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584902/get-closest-number-out-of-array)

```js
var counts = [100, 200, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 600, 700, 750, 800, 900],
goal = 320;

var closest = counts.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return (Math.abs(curr - goal) < Math.abs(prev - goal) ? curr : prev);
});

console.log(closest);
```

```js
var valores = [100, 200, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 600, 700, 750, 800, 900],
valor = 330;

var maisProximo = valores.reduce(function(anterior, corrente) {
  return (Math.abs(corrente - valor) < Math.abs(anterior - valor) ? corrente : anterior);
});

console.log(maisProximo);
```

> [reduce()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ff679975(v=vs.94).aspx)  percorre o array da esquerda para a direita invocando uma função de retorno em cada elemento, ou melhor, serve para iterar sobre um array e utilizar o valor de cada item para criar um objeto final com base em alguma regra.
>
> [Math.abs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/09bx9f48(v=vs.94).aspx) retorna o valor absoluto de um número

Answer (score 1):

Esta função encontra o valor mais próximo, tanto o menor quanto o maior, respectivamente.

Na função tem 2 parâmetros, `ideais` e `valor`, onde `ideais` é um array com os valores ideais, e `valor` é o número que o usuário informar.

**Função:**

```
function valorMaisProximo(ideais, valor) {
    var lo = -1, hi = ideais.length;
    while (hi - lo > 1) {
        var mid = Math.round((lo + hi)/2);
        if (ideais[mid] <= valor) {
            lo = mid;
        } else {
            hi = mid;
        }
    }
    if (ideais[lo] == valor) hi = lo;
    return [ideais[lo], ideais[hi]];
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```
valorMaisProximo([200, 300, 500, 700], 400) // Retorna [300, 500]
```

Eu apenas copiei e modifiquei um pouco a função para melhor entendimento, mas a fonte desse código é [Essa Resposta Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4431347/7029618)